# Teleric charts memory leak in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, memory-leaks, telerik

We use  telerics charts(HTML5 Kendo UI libs )  in  our solutions and we need refresh data every 15 seconds. Charts use svg for showing result.
and unfortunately we have memory leak after  1 hour work   in IE(version 10 and 11). IE takes more than 1 gb memory after 1 hours and after 2 hours IE crashes.

Chrome and firefox work fine. The trouble accures only in IE.
I assume the main problem is - How to work IE with svg

and the most important thing - Memory leak accure in IE, Javascript heap do not have the trouble with memory. 
When IE take 2 gb memory. Js heap have size 50-100 mb.

It guess that problem in IE and not in my js code or teleric code

By the way we use teleric with angular but I hope it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest that you try one of the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Try upgrading to the latest Kendo UI version. Currently this is
   version 2016.2.607.
2. Ensure IE is not in compatibility mode or the browser and the
   document mode are not different. If that is the case you can force
   the browser to edge mode.
3. Ensure you are destroying the kendo widget -
   docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/destroy
4. Use Canvas render mode instead of SVG.
5. Try the troubleshooting steps from this article -
   http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/troubleshoot/troubleshooting-memory-leaks#memory-leaks
6. If you are suing Angular JS try this - http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/Troubleshooting/leak

If the above information doesn't help it would be better to share an example where the issue can be reproduced and investigated.